# Empty Array inside Redux Action map object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm getting an object from an action (using axios) and using a map function to iterate it.

I also need to get another action but inside the parent object mapped.
I see that the request/response are ok (with returned data), but the reducer variable still gets empty.

## 1: component gets data

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { match: { params } } = this.props;
        this.props.getSaleDetails(params.order_id);
      }
```

## 2: defining mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

```
const mapStateToPropos = state => ({
    saleDetails: state.salesOrders.saleDetails,
    saleDetailFurthers: state.salesOrders.saleDetailFurthers
   });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators({ getSaleDetails, getDetailFurthers }, dispatch);
```

## 3: creating a const from the redux props

```
const detailsArray = saleDetails.data;
```

## 4: iterate array with map function

```
// getDetailFurthers is another action, getting data by passing "detail_id" and updating "saleDetailFurthers" props

{detailsArray && detailsArray.map((item) => {
                    const {getDetailFurthers, saleDetailFurthers} = this.props;
                    getDetailFurthers(item.detail_id)
                    console.log(saleDetailFurthers)
// empty array????
                    count++;
                    return (
                        <Paper className={classes.paper} key={item.detail_id}>
// ... next code lines
```

## 5: Actions

```
export function getDetailFurthers(detail_id){
    return async dispatch => { 
        const request =  await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/salesorders/detail/furthers/${detail_id}`)
        return {
            type: "SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED", 
            payload: request
        }
    }
}
```

## 6: Reducers

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  //... others
  saleDetailFurthers: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ///... other cases
    case "SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED":
      return { ...state, saleDetailFurthers: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

I expect the "saleDetailFurthers" const be loaded with data from redux action.

Comment: tried to use  **SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED** instead **"SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED"** in Reducer and your Action

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dispatch instead of returning, like so:

```
dispatch({
  type: "SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED", 
  payload: request
});
```

Comment: It worked. But it caused an infinite loop request (axios.get).

Comment: So when your component first renders it will map over detailsArray and the callback function will call the action creator getDetailFurthers() to fetch data. Once getDetailFuthers() completes the axios call, it will change the redux state and thus cause a re-render of your component since your component is connected to  "saleDetailFurthers". Since your component re-renders it will map over detailsArray again and then call getDetailFurthers() and so an infinite loop will happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function getDetailFurthers(detail_id) => dispatch =>{
    const request =  await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/salesorders/detail/furthers/${detail_id}`)
    dispatch ({
        type: "SALE_DETAIL_FURTHERS_FETCHED", 
        payload: request
    })
}
```

Comment: Dispatch expects an object. Correct your answer.